# Connection to pypi.org timed out error while installing Selenium Python clients on Windows 10 system

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can't figure out how to install selenium. I am using Windows Command Processor and typing in:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

(also tried pip install selenium)

When installing I am getting a Connection timeout error as follows:

```
connection to pypi.org timed out.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost there. Instead of `U-selenium` you need to use `-U selenium`. So effectively your line of code will be:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Comment: sorry mistake in my question I did type -U selenium, had the same issue